# Not getting expected result while runing java through cmd prompt

Tags: java

I have been using IDEs to execute java programs and I am completely new in running java programs through command prompt. File structure of my `javacodes` directory looks like this:

[image]

`JdbcDriverTest3` class is defined as follows:

```java
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class JdbcDriverTest3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Enumeration<Driver> e = DriverManager.getDrivers();

        while(e.hasMoreElements()){

            Driver d = e.nextElement();
            System.out.println(d.getClass());
            System.out.println(d.getClass().getName());

        }

    }   

}
```

I have run following commands in my command prompt :

```
C:\javacodes>javac   JdbcDriverTest3.java

C:\javacodes>java  -Djdbc.driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" JdbcDriverTest3
```

The code should print driver class name. But it is giving nothing in response.  Please suggest me the correct way of using java related commands. Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** The intention of using java code mentioned above is to know *how driver class colud be loaded through command prompt*.

Comment: Do you want to pass Driver name as argument through cmd ?

Comment: No  i want to pass driver name through `-Djdbc.driver` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using semicolons like:

```
java -cp ;ojdbc14.jar; -Djdbc.drivers=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver JdbcDriverTest3
```

The code will be:

```
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;

public class JdbcDriverTest3 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //Class driverClass = Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        //DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) driverClass.newInstance());

        Enumeration<Driver> e = DriverManager.getDrivers();

        while(e.hasMoreElements()){

            Driver d = e.nextElement();
            System.out.println(d.getClass());
            System.out.println(d.getClass().getName());

        }
    }
}
```

Compile and run like this:

```
C:\javacodes>javac   JdbcDriverTest3.java

C:\javacodes>java -cp ;ojdbc14.jar; -Djdbc.drivers=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver JdbcDriverTest3
```

Out put:

```
class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Comment: Just FYI, it's been 20 years since you no longer had to write code like `Class driverClass = Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");`. If the JDBC driver class is on the classpath, the jdbc connection string is all you need to specify - java will handle the rest.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the system property is `jdbc.drivers` with an `s` at the end. Change your command line to:

```
java -Djdbc.drivers=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver JdbcDriverTest3
```

You can find more details in the [Javadoc of `java.sql.DriverManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html)

The above assumes that you have set up your CLASSPATH environment variable correctly. Given the directory structure from your screenshot, you can also, as a quick test, try:

```
java -cp ojdbc14.jar:. -Djdbc.drivers=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver JdbcDriverTest3
```

Comment: I have tried the command mention above... still it is not working.

Comment: @Nithin you need to make sure that your CLASSPATH is set up correctly. See edit to the answer.

Comment: I have run  `test.java`  (It prints "Hello world") belonging to some directory. It is printing the string mentioned in the code. Does that ensure my classpath is correct ??